# SQL Where date1 is 3 days bigger than date2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-arithmetic

I try to filter rows where date1 (importTime) is always 3 days older than the other date2 (time).

Tried to Query rows from a Azure Database.

```
WHERE
instagramInsightsOwnPosts.importTime 

((3 days older than))

instagramInsightsOwnPosts].time
```

I'd expect to show only the rows where the date1 is 3 days older than date2.

Answer (score 2):

> I try to filter rows where date1 (importTime) is always 3 days older than the other date2 (time).

Isn't this a simple `where` condition?

```
where importTime <= dateadd(day, -3, time)
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. With this it worked:

[instagramInsightsOwnPosts].[importTime] 
BETWEEN 
DATEADD(HOUR, 72, [instagramInsightsOwnPosts].[time]) 
AND DATEADD(HOUR, 96, [instagramInsightsOwnPosts].[time])

Answer (score 0):

With this it worked:

```
[instagramInsightsOwnPosts].[importTime] 
    BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, 72, [instagramInsightsOwnPosts].[time]) 
        AND DATEADD(HOUR, 96, [instagramInsightsOwnPosts].[time])
```